# Relatively prime to $42$ and $70$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots, gcd-and-lcm

How many numbers are relatively prime to $42$ and $70$?

There's no set limit (i.e. numbers relatively prime must be less than $42$ or $70$), so I'm unsure how to figure this out. I think I'm overthinking this problem! Any hints?

(This came from a primitive roots of unity problem.)

Comment: This needs clarification...are you counting, say, 101 as a number relatively prime to 42 and 70?

Comment: @lulu: If it helps, the original problem was: If A is the set of primitive 42nd roots of unity and B is the set of primitive 70th roots of unity, how many elements do A and B have in common?

Comment: It would help to look at prime factorizations. If numbers are relatively prime they must share no prime factors

Comment: The answer to the real problem, though, is $0$. A number can't be a primitive $m,n$th root of unity if $m$ is different from $n$.

Comment: @Math is Life.  But...well, saying $\xi$ is an r-th root of unity means that $\xi^r= 1$ and saying it is primitive means that r is the smallest positive solution to that equation.  Thus, there could not be any $\xi$ which was both a primitive $42^{nd}$ and a primitive $70^{th}$ root of unity.

Comment: @lulu: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: So next time ask the original problem and then tell us that you think you have reduced it to this (the one you asked). As you can see, the two are totally different.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are aiming at, but looking at the prime factorizations of $42$ and $70$ a number $n$ is relatively prime to both numbers if and only if gcd$(n,2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7)=1$. Now take $n$ to be any power of $11$ for example, or any prime larger than $7$. This gives you an infinite set.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your original problem as mentioned in comments:

Primitive $42$th roots of unity are the the set $\{e^{\frac{2\pi\iota k_1}{42}\ }\ |\ (k_1,42)=1\}$ and set of primitive $70$th roots of unity is $\{e^{\frac{2\pi\iota k_2}{70}\ }\ |\ (k_2,70)=1\}$.

Now when $e^{\frac{2\pi\iota k_1}{42}}=e^{\frac{2\pi\iota k_2}{70}} where (k_1,42)=1$ and $(k_2,70)=1$

Zero.